# Send files from android device to server?

Tags: php, android, file-upload

How to send all files from sdcard to server i can push file from device to server through this
Code :

```
public void btnclick(View v) {

        String pathToOurFile = "/mnt/sdcard/" + "q.3gp";
        String urlServer = "http://www.google.com/upload.php";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

        try {

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    pathToOurFile));

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", "gopivideo");
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream
                    .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"sample\";filename=\""
                            + pathToOurFile + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                    + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    serverResponseCode + "," + serverResponseMessage,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Exception handling
        }
    }
}
```

This is working cool for uploading any type of file to server with single push
but what is need is to loop all files in sdcard and send one by one.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Multipart post request:(This way, you dont need to create json)

```
   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(serverURL);
    MultipartEntity postEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    File file = new File("Your File path on SD card");
    postEntity.addPart("fileupload", new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg"));
    postEntity.addPart("loginKey", new StringBody(""+loginKey));
    postEntity.addPart("message", new StringBody(message));
    postEntity.addPart("token", new StringBody(token));
    post.setEntity(postEntity);
    response = client.execute(post);
```

and add [Mime4](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime4j/?source=dlp)  library

Comment: Thanks for your post but there is no loop in your code i already used this what i need is to loop all type of files in an sdcard and to send or do it one by one with single button click i am an beginner to android please help me with this.

Comment: By byte array you can send the file, and can retrive from server and you have to decode the file